# Optimisation time process Linq request

Tags: c#, linq, optimization, time

I have this resquest bellow And I would like to know if there are ways to optimise the time processing of it ?

```
var relevantQuantities2 = AllOrders
                                .GroupBy(item => new {item.CreatedTime, item.Quantity})
                                .Where(group => group.Any(item => item.Tag == "Name1") &&
                                                group.Any(item => item.Tag == "Name2"))
                                .OrderByDescending(item => item.Key.CreatedTime).Take(1)
                                .Select(g => g.Key.Quantity).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: `group.Any(item => item.Tag == "Name1")` should be a OR condition actually ... you don't need `FirstOrDefault()` since you are taking only 1 record with `Take(1)`

Comment: @Rahul "_you don't need FirstOrDefault() since you are taking only 1 record with Take(1)_" Although the `IEnumerable` will only iterate over 1 item, that item still needs to be extracted.

Comment: Try following where before the GroupBy which may speed up time : AllOrders.Where(item => (item.Tag == "Name1") || (item.Tag == "Name2"))

Comment: @Rahul, Johnathan Barclay, jdweng I have an other class which can change the Tag, so I must to use AND instead of OR. I try your proposition jdweng :)

Comment: var relevantQuantities1 = AllOrders
        .Where(item => (item.Tag == "Name1") && (item.Tag == "Name2"))
           .GroupBy(item => new {item.CreatedTime, item.Quantity})
           .OrderByDescending(item => item.Key.CreatedTime).Take(1)
           .Select(g => g.Key.Quantity).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: The request upper doesn't work like the initial, the result is not the same. And with a first() method instead of firstOrDefault() i get a "Sequence contains no elements". Weird because i check if relevantQuantities1 != null && != 0 before use it.

Comment: @guerinremi The OR was correct - you must OR before the `GroupBy` and then you can do the `Where` with AND after the `GroupBy` - you were not supposed to remove the `Where` after the `GroupBy`. Is this LINQ to Objects or are you using a database?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends a little bit on what your data looks like also.
What performs well with one set of values, might not perform so well with another set of values.

If you want to performance enhance your algorithm:

Isolate the dataset you validating against, so that you know precisely what data you are supposed to get, and then measure the time it takes to return the result.

The make the same algorithm run over different sets of data, or a data set that mimics your production data values as closely as possible. (Identical is best, but often production data isn't static, and it is worth to try to anticipate what the data values will look like in a year, or 5 or ten)

And that using various versions of the current algorithm, to validate both actual resulting data, and the time your versions spent calculating said response.

Now compare result times for your individual sets, is there a version that is fastest on them all? Then use that, if not, time for a deeper look at your data and why that might be.

Comment: Hello Mortens, I work on Quantconnect, web IDLE Quant platform. I dont have the control on the API and on how the DataSet is build.

Comment: @Sinatr
Well, you see, The answer is there: "How do you optimize your algorith" those are step by step instructions. 

But in the answer, I am also asking him questions he should have asked himself. 

I could put it in the comments, but there isn't enough room, and technically, I did answer. That you are claiming there isn't an answer, I can't help you there however.

Comment: @guerinremi

Create a "fake" dataset. either by copying the dataset you receive from the API into a local dataset you can re-create on command. (Like a JSON object you deserialize and serialize in a test) 
And then try to run different versions of the algorithm on that dataset

Comment: @guerinremi Or, setup a test that spams the heck out of the production system :)
I would recommend you create a local data set to test from. 

And then try to alter the algorithm, and time how long it takes as each version of your algorithm processes it. 

Try to de-crease or increase the dataset size to see if that effects the various versions of your algorithm.

Comment: @Mortens Bork, Do it will be to hack the platform. Data is not free, cast or copying it is not in my interest... But If you want to try to test vulnerability and tell it to quantco team, you can, i think they will appreciate !

Comment: The input data is time stamped for 1 minute. Every 1 minute, an aggregate of data is analyzed by the algo.

Answer (score 0):

What you call `item` is in fact an `Order`.

First you make groups of `Orders` that have the same `{CreatedTime, Quantity}` combination:

```
AllOrders.GroupBy(order => new {order.CreatedTime, order.Quantity})
```

The result is a sequence of groups. Every group has a Key `{CreatedTime, Quantity}`; every group is a sequence of Orders that have this Key.

Then you filter your groups of Orders. You only want to keep those groups of Orders that have at least one Order with a Tag equal to "Name1" AND at least one Order with a Tag equal to "Name2"

```
.Where(group => group.Any(order => order.Tag == "Name1")
             && group.Any(order => order.Tag == "Name2"))
```

So you take the first Order of the group. Does it have Tag=="Name1"? No. Take the 2nd Order of the group. Does it have Tag=="Name1". No. Etc. until you found the Tag on the 20th Order

Then you start again at the first Order. Does it have a Tag=="Name2"? No. Etc. Until you found the Tag on the 15th Order.

The problem is, that when searching for "Name1", you already found that the first Order didn't have "Name2". You also saw the 15th Order, which had the Name2, but you were looking for Name1.

The result is that you have to enumerate your sequence twice.

What you would like to do is remember that you saw Name2, until you also see Name1.

Make an extension method like `Any`, that checks two predicates, and returns true as soon as it found an element that matched predicate1 as well as an element that matches predicate2:

```
public static bool Any<Tsource>(this IEnumerable<Tsource> source,
       Func<Tsource, bool> predicate1,
       Func<Tsource, bool> predicate2)
{
    // TODO: exception if source or predicates null
    bool predicate1Met = false;
    bool pedicate2Met = false;

    using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        // enumerate every element, and check for every element if the predicates are met
        // don't check on predicates that are already met
        // stop as soon as both predicates are met.
        while (enumerator.MoveNext() && !predicate1Met && !predicate2Met)
        {
            // There is a next element in the source. predicates not met yet
            // check the predicates on this element
            // but only if the predicates are not met yet
            predicate1met = predicate1met || predicate1(enumerator.Current);
            predicate2met = predicate2met || predicate2(enumerator.Current);
        }
    }

    // if here, all elements enumerated, or both predicates met
    return predicate1met && predicate2met;
}
```

So now you can optimize your `Where`:

```
.Where(group => group.Any(item => item.Tag == "Name1",    // predicate 1
                          item => item.Tag == "Name2"))   // predicate 2
```

After the where you order all groups by descending value of CreatedTime. Then you throw away most of these ordered groups:

```
.OrderByDescending(item => item.Key.CreatedTime)
.Take(1)
.Select(g => g.Key.Quantity)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

Wouldn't it be better to just find the group with the largest CreatedTime? That way you don't have to enumerate the group  more than once. You want some kind of `Max or default` method where you can decide on which key you want to Maximize.

Again: let's make a LINQ like extension method. Just like we see in LINQ we create overloads with and without a comparer.

```
public static TSource MaxOrDefault<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    Func<TSource, TResult> resultSelector)
{
    // call the Max method with a null comparer
    return MaxOrDefault(source, keySelector, resultSelector, null);
}
```

The overload with the comparer:

```
public static TSource MaxOrDefault<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    this Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    Func<TSource, TResult> resultSelector,
    IComparer<TKey> comparer)
{
    // TODO: exception if input null, allow null comparer
    if (comparer == null) comparer = Comparer<TKey>.Default();

    // enumerate the sequence
    var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
    if (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        // the source has at least one element. For now this is the max:
        TSource max = enumerator.Current;
        TKey maxKey = keySelector(max);

        // are there larger elements in source? let's enumerate the rest
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            TKey currentKey = keySelector(enumerator.Current);
            if (comparer.Compare(currentKey, maxKey) > 0)
            {
                // we found a larger element:
                max = enumerator.Current;
                maxKey = currentKey;
            }
        }

        // all elements are enumerated. Create the result
        TResult result = resultSelector(max);
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        // the source is empty; return default:
        return default(TResult);
    }
}
```

This will replace `OrderBy(...).Take().Select(...).FirstOrDefault by:

```
.MaxOrDefault(group => group.Key.CreatedTime,   // keySelector: get the max value
              group => group.Key.Quantity)      // resultSelector: when found use this
```

So your complete LINQ will be:

```
var result = AllOrders
    .GroupBy(order => new {order.CreatedTime, order.Quantity})
    .Where(group => group.Any(item => item.Tag == "Name1",
                              item => item.Tag == "Name2"))
    .MaxOrDefault(group => group.Key.CreatedTime,
                  group => group.Key.Quantity);
```

So how many times will you enumerate your sequence:

- Once to make groups
- Every group at utmost once until you've found the tags
- The remaining groups: only the keys of the groups, not the orders in the group: once

So if your 1000 orders will result in 10 groups, and you need to check every group for about half to find the Tags. It might be that all orders in a group without a tag are enumerated, but then again: you won't use them anymore.

Finally, from the remaining groups, you only enumerate the keys once.

The nice thing is, that `Any with two predicates` and `MaxOrDefault with predicate`, are fairly useful methods, that you probably will use in other situations. Especially the MaxOrDefault is one that I use regularly in cases similar to FirstOrDefault. The standard Max doesn't work with empty sequences.

### Further optimization

I think you can optimize it even more by putting everything in one extension method. However this method won't be reusable. But you can do it while enumerating your sequence only once.

```
public int ToMaxNewestOrder(this IEnumerable<Order> orders)
{
    // create a Dictionary with key `{CreatedTime, Quantity}`.
    // Values are the booleans: name1Found, name2Found
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<Tuple<DateTime, int>, Tuple<bool, bool>();

    foreach (var order in orders)
    {
        bool tag1Mach = order.Tag == "Name1");
        bool tag2Mach = order.Tag == "Name2");
        var orderKey = Tuple.Create(order.CreatedTime, order.Quantity);

        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(orderKey, out Tuple<bool, bool, int> value)
        {
            // the key is in the dictionary. Update the tags
            value.Item1 = value.Item1 || tag1Match);
            value.Item2 = value.Item1 || tag2Match);
        }
        else
        {
            // this key not in dictionary yet
            dictionary.Add(orderKey, Tuple.Create(tag1Match, tag2Match));
        }
    }

    // all order processed. We only need to enumerate the KeyValues from the dictionary
    // to keep the ones with boot tags matching
    // remember the maximum value for quantity

    int maxQuantity = 0;
    foreach(var keyValuePair in dictionary)
    {
        if (keyValuePair.Value.Item1     // any of the Tags matches name1 
        &&  keyValuePair.Value.Item2     // any of the Tags matches name2
        &&  keyValuePair.Key.Quantity > maxQuantity)
        {
            maxQuantity = quantity;
        }
    }
    return maxQuantity;
}
```

Now you are certain that you enumerate the sequence only twice: once all Orders, and once all Groups. If every Order has different CreatedTime and Quantity, then every Order will be in its own group. The maximum will be that you enumerate the Orders twice.

Comment: Hello Harald, I will past some hours to print it in my brain what you have gratefully posted, many many Thanks !!!

Comment: Hello Harald, do you know a site where it is explained how information is processing step by step in a request linq ? Or More globaly in programmation ? I don't suceed to integrate your code in my algo and i think i need to understand the logic more deeply.

Comment: Example how to manually enumerate: GetEnumerator / MoveNext / Current: See c# program that uses GetEnumerator() on [this page](https://www.dotnetperls.com/getenumerator). To create an enumerable with yield return see [this example](https://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2016/05/12/yield-return-in-c/). Most LINQ methods use yield return, or GetEnumerator / MoveNext to iterate. See [source code Enumerable](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs.html) See also [All standard LING operators](https://odetocode.com/articles/739.aspx)

Comment: To create your own LINQ methods, use an extension method. See [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)